# Trying to fill a combobox using another combobox PHP / Javascript

Tags: php, html

So, I wanna change, using values from a comboBox, another comboBox values (from database MYSQL ). Don't know where the problem is but thinking about that function. 
Sorry for my english btw, isn't my native language.

Here are my dropdown lists in HTML:

```
<select name="Discipline" id="DisciplineList">
 <?php include "combo1.php"; 
 ?>
</select>

</div>
<div class="alegere2">
<?php echo "Alegeti lectia:" ;
?>
<select name="lectie" id="lectieList">
</select>
```

Here is the code that I use to fill the second dropdown list using the  values from the first one:

```
  < script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).on("change","#DisciplineList",function(){

  var val = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({

               url: "combo2.php",
               data: {Discipline:val},
               type: "GET" ,
               dataType: "html",
               success: function(result){

                    $("#lectieList").html(result); 
               }
          });
   });
   < /script>






 Here is the first comboBox fill: ( it fills corectly)

   <?php 
require("db.php");
$results = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT nume,id FROM discipline");
  $nr_discipline=mysqli_num_rows($results);
 while($nr_discipline > 0){
   $row = mysqli_fetch_row($results);
    echo '<option value="'.$row[1].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';
    $nr_discipline--;

  }

  ?>
```

Here is the 2nd comboBox code : (isn't working )

```
          <?php   
// Connects to your Database 
 require("db.php");

  $id_discipline = $_GET['Discipline'];

  $Query= "SELECT nume,id FROM lectii WHERE id_disciplina =2";

  $lectie = mysqli_query($db,$Query);
 $nr_lectie = mysql_num_rows($lectie);

 while ($nr_lectie > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($lectie);

   echo '<option value="'.$row[1].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';
  $nr_lectie--;
   }
?>
```

I don't know where is the problem. It looks like the function is not working at all.

Comment: There are (at least) a couple things wrong with this. First, `dataType: "json",` says that you're expecting json, back. Obviously, that's not what's happening.  Second, even if you didn't have that wrong, you'd be trying to inject `<script>` tags and raw text into a `<select>` element, which won't work so well.

Comment: I edited the data type Json to Html , but still not working ;s

Comment: Ah btw, now it sends me the test msg "message succesfuly sent" after I change the values of the combobox ( first one).

Comment: Did you see the second part of what I wrote? The only thing you should be `echo`ing is the html for the `option`s.  Combine that with phpdroid's answer and you should be on the right track.  Check your browser's developer tools Network tab to see the data sent back by the server.

Comment: I corrected the raw text and I left there just the Options of the Select, but still not working . (also corected what phpdroid said )

Comment: You need to define what "not working" means.  Specifically, what _is_ happening? Are you getting a response from the server? If so, what?  Have you check to see if any javascript errors are reported in your browser console? Have you tried calling the PHP code directly (not via javascript ajax)?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/gc6via  , this is a printscreen at the console from browser after I click on a combobox value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#lectie").html(result);
```

here **lectie** is class not id replace lectie by **lectieList** that is the id

Comment: Thanks for answer , but the problem is still there ;s

Comment: Any other ideeas? :S

Comment: Working now :D , hehe

Comment: please select the answer